# Check whether context user is having "view all" permission on an object

Tags: permissions, profile

I want to check whether context user is having "view all" permission on an object or not. Is there any way to know that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure!

Check the `ObjectPermissions` table and here's the [Entity Rel. Diagram](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_profile_permissions.htm).

```
SELECT SobjectType, PermissionsViewAllRecords, PermissionsModifyAllRecords
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE Parent.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
ORDER BY SobjectType 
LIMIT 10
```

In Apex it could even be `WHERE SobjectType = 'Account' AND Parent.ProfileId = :UserInfo.getProfileId()`.

Answer (score 2):

@Eyescream is on the right track, but you'll also want to take into account permission sets which can also grant the view all perm.  Here's an example function that checks both

```
public Boolean hasViewAllPerm(Id userId, Id profileId, String sObjectType) {
    Integer permSetCheck = [
        select count()
        from ObjectPermissions
        where sObjectType = :sObjectType
            and PermissionsViewAllRecords = true
            and parentId in (
                select permissionSetId 
                from PermissionSetAssignment 
                where assigneeId = :userId
            )
    ];
    Integer profileCheck = [
        select count()
        from ObjectPermissions
        where sObjectType = :sObjectType
            and PermissionsViewAllRecords = true
            and parent.profileId = :profileId
    ];
    return (permSetCheck + profileCheck) > 0;
}
```